# Как в Asp.Net реализовать динамическую кодогенерацию?

Tags: c#, кодогенераторы

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с кодогенерацией, создавать обычные классы. В начале использовал CodeDom, но перейдя на более поздние .Net не смог реализовать это через CodeDomProvider, так как подобные операции не поддерживаются на данной платформе (во всяком случае так писалось в ошибке). Затем нашёл такую вещь, как Roslyn, но толковые примеры не могу найти, видел лишь как генерируется как бы текст кода, однако что с ним потом делать и как из него делать реальный класс и внедрять в проект - непонятно.

Comment: можете попробовать [`SourceGenerator`-ы](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/)

Comment: Текст класса - это и есть реальный класс и внедряется в проект точно так же, как и любой другой.